# Array_combine in foreach loop or what?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Now,i have a big problem with a foreach cycle and the array.

I want to insert in a MySQL table with 2 column (codice,giacenza) the value stored in a txt file. This is the example of the txt file:

> *$S0AE7375             $L01$F003$T017$B00000002$I001$G00201$R00000000$O03$N*
>   *$S0AE8909             $L01$F001$T017$B00000006$I001$G00201$R00000000$O03$N*

With a parsing i have obtainde what i have serched,i simple file with the value codice and giacenza. This is the parsin.php file:

```
<?php
 $file = file_get_contents("./upload/magazzino.txt");
 $file2 = str_replace ("B00000", "", $file);
 $file3 = str_replace ('$S', '$', $file2);
 $rows = explode("\n", $file3);

 foreach($rows as $row) { 
     $linee  = explode ("$", $row);
     echo $linee[1].$linee[5]. "<br>\n";
    }
?>
```

I have use the `echo` in the `foreach` loop to see what happens and which is the result, and the result is this:

> 0AE7375 002
>   0AE8909 006

The first is the codice (0AE7375,ecc..) and the second are the giacenza (002,ecc..) but codice and giacenza isn't a single array,but two different. I thought to use array_combine because for a codice corresponds a giacenza,but i don't know if is correct.

Finally i have to insert the value in a SQL table with the insert method.

Hanyone have a idea to solve this problem? I have tried various solution but i don't know i have to use in the `foreach` cycle.

I have tried this but don't function:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO prodotti
         ($linee[1] , $linee[5] )
         VALUES
         ('codice', 'giacenza' )") OR DIE(mysql_error());
```

Comment: syntax for mysql insert is: ``INSERT INTO prodotti(codice, giacenza) values ('val1', 'val2')`` (assiming that ``codice`` and ``giacenza`` are field names in your database)

Comment: Now it's all ok,i have forgotted the correct query for sql... i'm an idiot -.-***

Comment: OK, so I'll make that an answer, please accept this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for mysql insert is: `INSERT INTO prodotti(codice, giacenza) values ('val1', 'val2')` (assuming that `codice` and `giacenza` are field names in your database)